# Android - Open resource from @drawable String

Tags: android

I have:

```
String uri = "@drawable/myresource.png";
```

How can I load that in ImageView? this.setImageDrawable?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If you really need to work with a string, try something like this:

```
private void showImage() {
    String uri = "drawable/icon";

    // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
```

Else I would recommend you to work with R.* references like this:

```
int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
```

Comment: I was loading the image name from some JSON, the URI didn't contain "drawable/" at the start and I wasn't getting a resource. In this case you can set the second parameter to `getIdentifier()` to "drawable"

Comment: keep in mind using it that android studio see it unused resource so "refactor/remove unused resources" option not work for it

Comment: Remember that you must don't add image extension to URI and must add "drawable/" to your first of URI

Answer (score 25):

First, don't do that, as that `@drawable` syntax is meaningless in Java code. Use `int resourceId=R.drawable.myresource`.

If for some reason you do wind up a resource name and need the integer ID, use `getIdentifier()` on the `Resources` object.

Comment: Thanks, after you gave me name of the method it was easy to find this page -> http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=35661

Answer (score 11):

you can also add your own variable.. in my case scene.name between i followed @pfleidi answers. c stands for context.

```
String uri = "drawable/" + scene.name; 
int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());

imageList.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Answer (score 6):

Long since overdue, but my favorite is to use the Context:

```
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
```

where **placeholder_image** is the id of the resource.  In your case, `R.drawable.myresource`.

Context can be an activity or the application.  Pretty much wherever you are has reference to the context, which you can use to get the application's context.

Comment: pfleidi's response is accessing the same method - Activities are Contexts, and so when he calls getResources(), he's using the current Activity as a context to get to the same place you did.  Edit: not quite the same, you're getting to the global Application context rather than using the Activity (or Service) context directly.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else comes across the problem I had, I was loading the image name from JSON and then needed to get the identifier. The second parameter of getIdentifier can be set to "drawable". This is a slight variation on @alia-ramli-ramli answer...

```
String uri = details.getString("circle").toLowerCase();

int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
viewHolder.unit_circle.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(stringfilename, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
iv_imageview.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,resID));
```

you can also retrieve image from mipmap by replacing "drawable" with "mipmap" parameter of getIdentifier() method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ... the deprecated etc. etc.
 I solved in such a way with minimum API 14 okay.

```js
...
...
ImageView imgPoster = viewCache.getImgPoster(resource);
String uri = "drawable/" + film.getPoster();
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResource);
imgPoster.setImageDrawable(image);

return convertView;
...
...
```