# How to replace R.drawable."someString"

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have some Images in my project. The name of the image is stored in a String and I would like to setImageResource(R.drawable."....."); with the string of the image name but the problem is that this is not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: where are the images present?

Comment: In the drawable of my project.

Comment: Its not a way work in android, You have to store images in drawable and access it by R.drawable.image

Answer (score 64, accepted):

this is not a right syntax, and you must getting compiler time error, before altering image resource you must know that, all resources provided an id, these ids are stored into R.java file. Ids are stored into integer format, and in your application you can fetch all these resources by these id, not by name, so you need to fetch id of resource at first, by:

```
String mDrawableName = "myimg";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

and then use this resID.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
getResources().getIdentifier("NAME_OF_IMAGE", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

Answer (score 3):

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string). It should help you. Basically you need to get the identifier and then load using `setImageResource`.

Answer (score 1):

public int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage);

name - name of the image

defType - it will be drawable for your case

defPackage - default package of your app (I think you can use getPackage() on the activity for this)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   String uri = "NAME";

    // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by moving the image from 'drawable' to 'raw' folder and access the string value as below.
If you do not have 'raw' folder under 'res' directory, right click on res->new->Android resource directory and under dropdown of resourcetype, select 'raw'.

```
    String avatar = ("android.resource://" + "yourPackageName/" + String.valueOf(R.raw.robot_blue));
```