# Android - Store drawable ids in a custom XML file

Tags: android, xml, parsing

In my app I'm using an xml file to store some data, and images are stored in the drawable folder. I would like to "link" these to, meaning that each object in the xml file to refer a certain image in the drawable folder. How could i acomplish this ?
Thanks!

```
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <picture>R.drawable.joe_pic</picture>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Dean</name>
        <picture>R.drawable.dean_pic</picture>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with only saving the name like "joe_pic" and can get [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string)

```
private void showImage() {
    String uri = "drawable/icon";

    // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
```

but if you have already added "R.drawable.joe_pic" complete can use String.split to get 3 rd string part