# How to display image in image view using xml in android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to display image in list view where images are stores in drawble folder and i trying to read through XML here is my XML code.

```
<music>
<song>
    <title>Live Shows</title>
    <thumb_url>@drawable/chat.png</thumb_url>
</song>
<song>
    <title>Space Bound</title>
    <thumb_url>@drawable/email_open.png</thumb_url>
</song>
```

Please help me i am new to android.

Comment: if its working then vote for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Parse xml and call the function given below

```
// imagePath - value of <thumb_url>@drawable/chat.png</thumb_url>
// imageView - view where image needs to be set
private void setImage(String imagePath,ImageView imageView)
{  

 String uriFromXML = imagePath;
 String suffix = ".png";
if ((uriFromXML != null) && (uriFromXML.startsWith("@")) && (uriFromXML.endsWith(suffix))) 
{
  int length = uriFromXML.length();
  int suffixLength = suffix.length();
  String uri = uriFromXML.substring(1, length - suffixLength);



  int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,getPackageName());

  Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
  imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I presume you are using the androidhive tut. In the lazy adapter class change this code `imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);`
 to `thumb_image.setImageResource(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL));`

Comment: okay but can you give the example or tell me how to give path of image in XML so i will get the image directly in the image view

Comment: @SquiredSquire I tried your code but it given error `The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)`.

Comment: @NishitPatel change the xml so it is displayed as file:///android_asset/chat.png and change to line to imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image); and move all images to assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in Xml

```
<music>
<song>
    <title>Live Shows</title>
    <thumb_url>chat</thumb_url>
</song>
<song>
    <title>Space Bound</title>
    <thumb_url>email_open</thumb_url>
</song>
```

and in activity,

```
int redId = getResources().getIdentifier("<your_package>:drawable/<resource_name>", null, null);
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
```

where  would be something like `com.example.package` and `<resource_name>` would be filled by `thumb_url` from your xml.

#### References: [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string) [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name)