# Getting Error in android -- the method setImageResource(int) is the type Image View is not applicable for the argument(string)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am trying to pass image from one activity to another activity using listview item, but I am getting this error line

> the method setImageResource(int)

is the type Image View is not applicable for the argument(string) and at this point of line:-

> lblImage.setImageResource(Image);

I don't know now what need to write to remove this error please someone support me and write the exact code to be fit on this line, here I am also placing some code for your reference:

```
    SingleMenuItem(Activity to fetch Image with some text data)::

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent

    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
    String Image = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    //Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap) in.getParcelableExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);

    // ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb_url);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    ImageView lblImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_label);

    //image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(artist);
    lblDesc.setText(duration);
    lblImage.setImageResource(Image); //Getting Error at this line only
    //the method setImageResource(int) is the type Image View is not
    // applicable for the argument(string)
    }
    }

    ActivityCode (to pass image and text data)
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
         // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById
                            (R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(
                             R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
            String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById
                            (R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
                  // byte[] array = null;
              // Bitmap thumb_url = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
                            (array, 0, array.length);
            String Image=((ImageView)view.findViewById
                            (R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();


            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent
                            (getApplicationContext(),  SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, Image);
            //in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
            startActivity(in);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a String to setImageResource(), which requires an integer.

Resource IDs are actually integers - when you refer in code to R.drawable.myImage this is referring to an integer resource in automatically generated code (R.java) which is created by the compiler.

To load an image from a resource *string* (not recommended) see [Android - Open resource from @drawable String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for image id not for image string

if you want show image in the imageview do it like this:

```
 lblImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

OR

according to your requirement you have to get Drawable from the imag link. by using this code you can get image drawable and then set to image view

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
   try {
      InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
      Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
      return d;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

call this function and the set drawable to image view like this.

```
Drawable image = LoadImageFromWebOperations(Image); // Image means iamge url getting                                     
                                                       from previous activity
imageview.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Comment: could you please tell me if i have images in listview and fetching from webURL so what i need to write and i have to get them by click on listview item on row basis, that was good what you have written and i have tried able to get that specific image into imageview......Please write some code for to get image of listview item

Comment: i was edited my answer look at that. it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks again i have tried this one but still getting errors, could you please edit my above source code as you wish they have to place in code...sorry but i am not able to fetch images from listview to imageview, it would be easy for me to understand and for further custom usage. i am getting xml data from this url :- http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml

Comment: you have to parse those xml code to the desired data.. you don't have image url in this class...