# Find drawable by string

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Open resource from @drawable String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string)

First of all sorry for the title but I don't know exactly what title I can set.

Ok, here's my question:

I will recibe from a external database a string for example: 'picture0001'.

In the folder res/drawable I have a picture which name is picture0001.

I would like to set that picture as background (source) of a ImageView.

The question is, how can I look for this picture with the string I got from the external database.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Yes, you can look it up by name using [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
Context context = imageView.getContext();
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("picture0001", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

It's not efficient, but it works to look up occasional resources.

Comment: @QuinDa Great! Don't forget to click the checkmark next to an answer if it worked for you--it'll help you get better answers from us in the future! ;)

Comment: I tried it but it says: Vote Up requires 15 reputation ):

Comment: @QuinDa The checkmark, not the up arrow (which, yes, needs 15 reputation). But it seems you found it already! :)

Comment: Storm the up vote!

Comment: keep in mind using it that android studio see it unused resource so "refactor/remove unused resources" option not work for it

Comment: Why don't it work for me? I get `id = 0`. Android replaced my strings like `@drawable/icon_empty` in the array with strings like `es/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon_empty.png` automatically.

Comment: I fixed it with the following code: `drawable = resources.getDrawable(resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.array_name).getResourceId(array_index, 0), context.getTheme());`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use reflection like this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("your.project.package.R");
Field f = c.getDeclaredField("drawable");
Class d = f.getDeclaringClass();
Field f2 = d.getDeclaredField("yourstring");
int resId = f2.getInt(null);
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
```

Though, the best solution is what MarvinLabs suggested.

Comment: I think `Resources.getIdentifier` is probably an easier method than this.

Comment: Yes but this solution is faster  (by more than 40%)

Comment: @An-droid - could you provide some source for this? i checked it and found the difference to be negligible. i also read that blogpost everyone keeps mentioning, but there are no metrics beside a dubious claim that reflection is 5 times faster.  To me it seems that the results only depend on where the resource is located in the R file (the more to the top, the faster the lookup).

Comment: @An-droid - i found the link to the post in case you would like to check: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.de/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html