# How to get a drawable using a string?

Tags: android

I know there are questions exactly like mine. I have looked at a couple and I have been using this one: 
[How can I convert String to Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856260/how-can-i-convert-string-to-drawable) . However when I use this code from this answer in my code drawable is always null.

His code:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Here is my code where this keeps happening.  The image view is in the right spot but there is no image there. When I run it with the debugger, the variable id gets what I think is the right integer value but I do not know of a way to confirm it.

```
String[] images = currExercise.get_allImg().split(",");
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(images[0], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
mainImage.setBackground(drawable);
```

Is there any alternative to doing this? Any suggestions is greatly appreciated and Thank you.

I am adding my entire Adapter class

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//song list and layout
private ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
private LayoutInflater exerciseInf;
private Context context;
private int screenWidth;
```

I am passing in the context. Is this what you mean?

```
//constructor
public ExerciseAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Exercise> allExercises, int sw){
    exercises=allExercises;
    exerciseInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    context = c;
    screenWidth = sw;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return exercises.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //map to song layout
    LinearLayout exerciseLay = (LinearLayout)exerciseInf.inflate(R.layout.exercise, parent, false);
    //get title and artist views

    ImageView exerciseMainImage = (ImageView)exerciseLay.findViewById(R.id.exerciseMainImage);
    exerciseMainImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int)Math.floor(screenWidth * .3);
    exerciseMainImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int)Math.floor(screenWidth * .3);
    LinearLayout exerciseContent = (LinearLayout)exerciseLay.findViewById(R.id.exerciseContent);
    exerciseContent.getLayoutParams().width = (int)Math.floor(screenWidth * .7);
    TextView titleView = (TextView)exerciseContent.findViewById(R.id.exerciseName);
    TextView entryView = (TextView)exerciseContent.findViewById(R.id.exerciseDescription);


    Exercise currExercise = exercises.get(position);

    String[] images = currExercise.get_allImg().split(",");
    /*Original*///exerciseMainImage.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(images[0], "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(images[0], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);

    /*Debug*///Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backlifts1);

    exerciseMainImage.setBackground(drawable);

    titleView.setText(currExercise.get_exerciseName());
    entryView.setText(currExercise.get_description());

    exerciseLay.setTag(position);
    return exerciseLay;
}
```

}

Comment: every resource file is saved with an resource id which is in integer, save this integers in your string array by converting them and check you have the same id as in R.java as in your string array. If you do, you can use it

Comment: when I am debugging I get a number like 2130837556 but in R.java it is 0x7f020034

Comment: 2130837556 is the number which you should have, R.java has hex numbers

Comment: Right well they are the same numbers

Comment: it is also not working if I use R.drawable.image from my drawable folder could it be that I am not in an activity and that I am in an adapter class for a listview?

Comment: ohh... so context were out of activity it self, see how getDrawable() returns it's type depending on it should tell you about the context as well.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean but in this line:   Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);   it returns null

Comment: don't worry you already solved the problem, in your adapter pass the context from your activity. and set this context passed from your activity to your adapter that you may get that integer using this context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70544/discussion-between-costas-vrahimis-and-pankaj-nimgade).

Comment: I updated the question I believe I am doing what you are saying right?

Comment: why don't you convert String array element into integer again and pass it to getDrawable(), method

Comment: Because it is just the file name