# How to change the ImageView source dynamically from a string? (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.android, drawable

I'm using Xamarin Android and I'm trying to change the ImageView src dynamically. All the pictures are placed in Resource/drawable. After reading the picture name as string from an xml (`string imgName = nameFromXml + ".jpg"`) I would like to passing it to my `ImageView`. I guess there are two good ways:

1) Get the image `(int)id` and passing it to the ImageView using SetImageResource(): 
`myTextView.SetImageResource(????????);`

2) Get the Uri of the of the Image

**EDIT**
Unfortunately I couldn't use Eric answer for QuinDa [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351003) because there are many methods not existing on Xamarin Android, working just in Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find drawable by string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351003/find-drawable-by-string)

Comment: Where is the XML that contains the name of the picture?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the standard Android method:

```
int resImage = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName , "drawable", getPackageName());
myTextView.setImageResource(resImage);
```

Please note that imgName variable must not contain file extension.

**`Xamarin.Android` C#:**

```
int resImage = Resources.GetIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", PackageName);
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tryied this way but `resImage` is always 0.

Comment: I've found another way:
`int resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField("myImageName").GetValue(null);`
then, just:
`imageView.SetImageResource(resourceId);`

Comment: I have also noticed that the image does not get picked up when the name contains a capital letter, make sure all the text is lowercase.

Comment: and what if we have 2 drawables with the same name and different extension? we can have an image.jpg and an vector image.xml

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to SushiHangover and Romuald for their answer, but I'd like to share another way that I tested and it looks working well.

Here's how I get the id of the resource:

```
int resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField("myImageName").GetValue(null);
```

So, then I'm able to use the normal SetImageResource():

```
imgViewCondition.SetImageResource(resourceId);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet solves the issue:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("XXX", "drawable", getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just this:

```
FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageviewName).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.nameofimage);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but it never hurt to help.

The image should be stored in all the proper sizes for android inside the Resources Folder
(drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi ....)

and then you get it dynamically like so

```
imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.YourImageNameHere);
```