# From JSON database use string for dimens

Tags: android, json, string

I am using a JSON database.
In it I prefer to have strings.

If I store something like "singleImage_marginTop" as a string in the JSON file, I can get the string, but how would I convert it into something that I could use here?

`image.setPadding(R.dimen.(the_string_to_be_used_here));`

Comment: [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351003/find-drawable-by-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context = image.getContext();
int padding = context.getResources().getIdentifier("the_string_to_be_used_here", "dimen", context.getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(padding);
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use it for a listview and for me non of the above mentioned solutions worked.

Instead I retreated to using a string to identify the given view's intended properties and based on that string I set the attributes for the different types of views in the listadapter.

It was a lot easier and safer that way.