# Can i set string concatenation in Resources id?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Have any possibility in java/kotlin

Q.
I have Resources>Drawable>image.xml
and in Activity
String assume = "image";/" image.xml"

can i set Drawable like iv.setImageResourse(R.drawable.assume);

any solution??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13351003