# Setting a drawable as a background from a String in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

I have an image with the name "simba.jpg" which I want to set as the background of a `LinearLayout` component. How can I do so?

A naive (and wrong) attempt at what I'm trying to do would be like so:

```
LinearLayout image = findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setBackground("simba.jpg");
```

The code I've tried from other posts (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351262/9686427) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369892/9686427)) do not work, either because they apply to an `ImageView` or because the methods used are deprecated.

Comment: [Use `setBackgroundResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)) along with the technique from the duplicate question.