# Open a resource file just with specific String variable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-resources

Sorry for the title, had troubles describing what I'm trying to do. I've always had this question for Java as a whole, but right now, its specific for Android. Let's say that I am parsing an API and get this special String, let's say `"clear"`. Inside my drawables, I have a `clear.jpg` that I would like to set as an ImageView programically . That's not the hard part. What I was wondering is if there was a quick way where I Could call on the .jpg with just the variable name? I know I can easily make different if statements, such as:

```
if(string == "clear")
{
    //setImageView to drawable/clear
}
```

but is there anyway I can do something such as

```
//setImageView to drawable/string
```

where string would be clear? I know obviously it would look for a string inside drawable, but is there anyway I could do what I'm describing? Just a general question I had; it was something I always wondered about.

Let me know! Thanks!

Comment: You can't do `string == clear`. Well you can, but I doubt it's what you're trying to do. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void showImage() {
    String uri = "drawable/icon";

    // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
```

Else I would recommend you to work with R.* references like this:

```
int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
  Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
```

Reference -> [Android - Open resource from @drawable String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string)

Answer (score 0):

With what i know, the quickest way to call up that picture is putting the

picture's name in the xml file; For instance if you want to change the background

of an imageview, you can just put in your xml file this code below

android:background="@drawable/clear".

Note the image must have been in the drawable folder. Thanks, i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. Not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Java 8 provides [limited support](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118) for local variable annotations, but its reflection API can't give you access within method bodies. So you'd need to parse the class file itself. And for that, a library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.equals("clear")){
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("clear", "drawable", getPackageName());
  imageView.setBackgroundResource(resID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as other ones at the point which is using `getIdentifier` method.

```
imageView.setImageView(getResources().getIdentifier(string, "drawable", 
            getPackageName()));
```

However, by doing this, you can process without if-condition block and just specify a Drawable of the value from `string` directly (I think it is your intention of this question).