# How to code Counter Images to change with Count++

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and i am making an application which has animated counter. each time i press count button count will increment and i want to change the ImageView image source according to count

i am doing this with if conditions while i want to do it dynamically because i have 9999 maximum count so i cannot write much if conditions for this

```
TextView textViewHeader;
static String value;
static int count;
static ImageButton imageButtonCountTasbeeh;
ImageView imageViewLsb,imageViewLsb1, imageViewLsb2, imageViewLsb3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasbeeh_counter);
    imageButtonCountTasbeeh = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCountTasbeeh);
    textViewHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextTasbeehName);
    imageButtonCountTasbeeh.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagebuttontasbeenpageselector);
    imageViewLsb = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLsb);
    imageViewLsb1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLsb1);
    imageViewLsb2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLsb2);
    imageViewLsb3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLsb3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("tasbeehName");
    }
    textViewHeader.setText(value);

    imageButtonCountTasbeeh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello you Just Clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            count++;
            if(count<10) {
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count, "drawable", getPackageName());
                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
            }else if(count<20 && count>=10)
            {
                int count1 = count-10;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n1);

            }else if(count<30 && count>=20)
            {
                int count1 = count-20;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n2);
            }else if(count<40 && count>=30)
            {
                int count1 = count-30;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n3);
            }else if(count<50 && count>=40)
            {
                int count1 = count-40;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n4);
            }else if(count<60 && count>=50)
            {
                int count1 = count-50;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n5);
            }else if(count<70 && count>=60)
            {
                int count1 = count-60;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n6);
            }else if(count<80 && count>=70)
            {
                int count1 = count-70;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n7);
            }else if(count<90 && count>=80)
            {
                int count1 = count-80;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count1, "drawable", getPackageName());

                imageViewLsb.setImageResource(resID);
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.n8);
            }



        }
    });




}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Open resource from @drawable String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
imageButtonCountTasbeeh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello you Just Clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         count++;             
         if (count > 999)
                imageViewLsb3.setImageResource(getResIdDrawableByNumber(count / 1000));

            if (count > 99 ) {
                int n100 = (count % 1000) / 100;
                imageViewLsb2.setImageResource(getResIdDrawableByNumber(n100));
            }

            if (count > 9) {
                int number10 = (count % 100) / 10;
                imageViewLsb1.setImageResource(getResIdDrawableByNumber(number10));
            }

            imageViewLsb.setImageResource(getResIdDrawableByNumber(count % 10));
    }
});
```

Use this method to get the corresponding image resource id by number value:

```
public int getResIdDrawableByNumber(int count){    
     return = getResources().getIdentifier("n" + count, "drawable", getPackageName());    
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your help!
this has worked for 1 Image View i have 4 image views accordingly

imageViewLsb
imageViewLsb1
imageViewLsb2
imageViewLsb3

Comment: Glad to help!! Please if you find our help valuable, dont forget to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: this is helpful for one ImageView but i have 4 ImageView which are representing 4 Digits
imageViewLsb imageViewLsb1 imageViewLsb2 imageViewLsb3

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood you...you have 4 imageView what do you want to achieve with this imageViewLsb1,imageViewLsb2,imageViewLsb3?

Comment: In your code you have only one `imageViewLsb` please edit your question and add your new imageView elements

Comment: i have posted code for all class. please suggest changes for ImageView

Thanks

Comment: I get your point, you are assing value to your ImageView according to the digits that they represent.

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't tested but I hope you get the point. Hope this helps...please don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Comment: i have tested your code but when count reaches 10 it disappears the 0

Comment: I create a sample project and fix some errors, now finally should work fine...so I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code has worked for my scenario

Regards,

Comment: Dear,

are you there? i need your help!

Comment: Hi, how can I help you?

Comment: Dear i am trying to sync my android contacts with web service but my code is not working and also stackoverflow is not allowing me to post question and asking to wait for few days

Comment: i have found AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter which can perform sync but i am unable to implement it in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by getting the `resource id` like this:

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Here you have to replace `nameOfDrawable` by `n1`, `n2`, .., `n9999`.

thus:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     count++;
     int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("n"+count, "drawable", this.getPackageName());           
     imageViewLsb.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
}
```