# Refer to a properties with a string

Tags: java, android

I've something like this

```
for (int i=0; i<dbHelper.cantidad_restaurants; i++) {
            datos.add(new clsRestaurants(R.drawable.res_1, "Este es el Restaurant 1", "Esta es la descripcion del REstaurant 1"));
            datos.add(new clsRestaurants(R.drawable.res_2, "Este es el Restaurant 2", "Esta es la descripcion del REstaurant 2"));
            datos.add(new clsRestaurants(R.drawable.res_3, "Este es el Restaurant 3", "Esta es la descripcion del REstaurant 3"));
            datos.add(new clsRestaurants(R.drawable.res_5, "Este es el Restaurant 5", "Esta es la descripcion del REstaurant 5"));
        }
```

I'd like instead of writing R.Drawable.Res_1 i could write something like

> "R.Drawable.Res_ + i "

Where I is the number of the for loop

Comment: [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349808/5130133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use getIdentifier and get int id

```
int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("Res_"+i, "drawable", "your.package.name");
```

Comment: So then i should pass 'resourceID' instead of R.drawable.?

Comment: yes, R.drawable. is int number and need pass 'resourceID' instead of R.drawable.

Comment: I'm getting an error...
 "Error:(27, 42) error: non-static method getResources() cannot be referenced from a static context" 

My line: 
"int resourceId = MainActivity.getResources().getIdentifier("Res_"+i, "drawable", "com.soft.kukito.cardviewprueba");"
----
I also tried: "int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier("Res_"+i, "drawable", "com.soft.kukito.cardviewprueba");"

Comment: imgV.setImageResource(resourceId); use this for use resourceId

Comment: But i can't put the the imgV, because i'm developing a dinamcally cardview, so i have only to tell the path where the image is located, changing only the last number.